# Java vector resizing could be problematic like in C++?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management

If I have, for example, an hashmap of this type:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer> > tag_posizioni;
tag_posizioni.put( "A",new ArrayList<Integer>() ); 
tag_posizioni.get("A").add(3);
```

So, I have resized my Arraylist associated with `A` tag; so, I have a new vector in a different memory zone; my next

```
tag_posizioni.get("A")
```

could throw a memory error (because my reference is pointing to a not valid memory zone) or JVM manage automatically this situation changing the reference?
Is more sure doing

```
ArrayList<Integer> pos=tag_posizioni.get("A");
pos.add(3);
tag_posizioni.put("A", pos);
```

or is useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code, when you call:

```
tag_posizioni.get("A").add(3);
```

then `tag_posizioni.get("A")` returns a reference to object on which `add(3)` is  called. This object (ArrayList) changes its internal data structures, what it does internaly is not known - it is encapsulated. Your statement would be true only if you were able somehow to take reference to this internal data structure (which is actually private to prevent you from doing this).

I think you are also asking whether adding alement to ArrayList might cause `tag_posizioni.get("A")` to return non valid memory. Under java there is no such thing like dangling pointers in C++, you may only have a null reference. Instance of array list which is referenced in `tag_posizioni.get("A")` will not modify its own reference in `tag_posizioni` HashMap.

In C++ situation is quite the same, when you use `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`, adding element to `std::vector<int>` might allocate more memory for vector but the whole process of reallocating buffer is encapsulated. But in C++ you are actually allowd to take pointer to internal vector memory which is not very wise - and might result in Undefined Behaviour.